# Linking boost_system when configured with apt-get install?

Tags: linux, boost, configuration, linker-errors, apt

Installed Cevelop 1.11.1

```
apt-get install g++-9
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 cpp-9 amd64 9-20190402-1ubuntu1 [8,861 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 libgcc-9-dev amd64 9-20190402-1ubuntu1 [2,355 kB]               
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 gcc-9 amd64 9-20190402-1ubuntu1 [9,643 kB]                      
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 libstdc++-9-dev amd64 9-20190402-1ubuntu1 [1,685 kB]            
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 g++-9 amd64 9-20190402-1ubuntu1 [10.1 MB]   

apt-get install libboost-dev
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 libboost1.67-dev amd64 1.67.0-13 [8,362 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 libboost-dev amd64 1.67.0.1 [3,228 B]
```

Specified boost_system for the linker. This produces an error.

```
g++-9 -std=c++1z -O0 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-attributes -fsanitize=undefined -pthread -o aptcp.o ../aptcp.cpp 
g++-9 -pthread -o aptcp aptcp.o -ltidy -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -lxalan-c -lxalanMsg -lxerces-c 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[sмurf states in his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/723225/10709):

> I would recommend installing package libboost-dev. It will install
>   whatever is the current version of boost for your system and will put
>   all files in the proper places.

Per [serup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40627272/101954) my understanding is that 'the library is installed'.

```
$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep boost_system | cut -d\> -f2
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.67.0
```

So, what is going on here?

The objective is to have a simple repeatable process for installing and using the compiler & libraries, one that builds upon the existing work of the developers & package maintainers. Is there a flaw in my understanding/expectations, in the packaging or the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The -l option will only find .a or .so library files, it will not find .so.1.67.0 or other.
That could be solved by creating a symbolic link:

```
ln -sf /your/path/to/libboost_system.so.1.67.0 /your/path/to/libboost_system.so
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

This installed all required symbolic links and static libraries for me on Ubuntu 19.04